# VBScript count specific elements in a form

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a form which is being used as a quiz to collect answers and is generated dynamically so the number of questions is variable.
I want to be able to count the number of radio button groups in the for so I can a)determine which where checked and b)be able to collect them so I can save the selected answers in a database.
Is this something I should try doing in jQuery and somehow passing it to VBScript or can this be done programatically in VBScript?
For reference, here's the generated HTML for an example form:

```html
<form id="vms_quiz" method="post">
<h2>Sustainable Infrastructure Quiz 1</h2>
<p>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</p>
<!-- START QUESTION GROUP: Question #1 -->
<h2>Question #1</h2>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_1" value="0" id="Q1C_1" akey="0" checked="false">
  Who</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_1" value="0" id="Q1C_2" akey="0" checked="false">
  What</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_1" value="1" id="Q1C_3" akey="1" checked="false">
  Where</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_1" value="0" id="Q1C_4" akey="0" checked="false">
  When</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_1" value="0" id="Q1C_5" akey="0" checked="false">
  Why</label>
<!-- START QUESTION GROUP: Question #2 -->
<h2>Question #2</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_2" value="0" id="Q2C_6" akey="0" checked="false">
  Who</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_2" value="0" id="Q2C_7" akey="0" checked="false">
  What</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_2" value="1" id="Q2C_8" akey="1" checked="false">
  Where</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_2" value="0" id="Q2C_9" akey="0" checked="false">
  When</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_2" value="0" id="Q2C_10" akey="0" checked="false">
  Why</label>
<!-- START QUESTION GROUP: Question #3 -->
<h2>Question #3</h2>
<p>Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed.</p>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_3" value="0" id="Q3C_11" akey="0" checked="false">
  Who</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_3" value="0" id="Q3C_12" akey="0" checked="false">
  What</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_3" value="1" id="Q3C_13" akey="1" checked="false">
  Where</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_3" value="0" id="Q3C_14" akey="0" checked="false">
  When</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Q_3" value="0" id="Q3C_15" akey="0" checked="false">
  Why</label>
<input name="vms_quizID" type="hidden" value="1">
<input name="vms_videoID" type="hidden" value="1">
<div class="frm_div">
  <input id="btn_quiz_check_answers" name="btn_quiz_check_answers" type="submit" value="Check Answers">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side VBScript is only available on Internet Explorer. You must use JavaScript (jQuery *is* JavaScript).

Comment: I came up with an array to keep the answers in which did exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the info about client-side VBScript.